# Linking Cell Infromation from on sheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of cells in Sheet 1 starting from A1 that I want to reference to a row of cells in Sheet 2 starting from A1. The idea would be to create a formula where this will automatically update and I won't have to manually create hyperlinks each time.

So far my Gf was been able to create a formula that partially works, but I'm curious if there is a better formula? There also are instances where I have spaces in between the cells in the Sheet 1 column, so dragging from the bottom right corner to copy won't work - is there a way around this?

The formula that she was able to create is:  **=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(COLUMN(A1),ROW(A1),4,1,"Sheet3"))**

We're struggling to find out how to have the hyperlink text, or "friendly name", be the text in the referenced cell (or the first 3 letters using a LEFT function).

I figured out how to add a friendly name "Go Here" 
**=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(COLUMN(A1),ROW(A1),4,1,"Sheet3"), "Go Here"**, 
but I don't know how to instead have the name be just the contents of the referenced cell, and have that update with each different cell.

The goal is to adjust the dates on the Source View **Sheet 2** (2nd photo), and text within the cells ie. week 1 - week 4 and information reflect the same on the Calendar View **Sheet 1** (1st photo).

[image: Calendar View]

[image: Source View]

[image: Workbook Pg 1]

[image: Workbook Pg 2]

Comment: (Does your mac not have a screenshot tool?)

Comment: @Bruce as Apple would have said, *our users don't need that*

Comment: @BruceWayne these pics were sent from my gf. Would it help you if you had screen shoots?

Comment: It'd be the same info, just without the extra stuff in the frame (and would be a little easier to read). No need to re-do, I was just curious.

Comment: @BruceWayne I understand, I've made the adjustments.

Comment: @pnuts Sorry I just followed the suggested tags. I'll make adjustments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say *Sheet2* column **A** is like:

[image]

and we want to insert hyperlinks on *Sheet1* column **A** to will get to them.  In *Sheet1* cell **A1** enter:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A" & ROWS($1:1),INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & ROWS($1:1)))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Notice that not only do you get the Hyperlink, but you get to see the contents of the cell you are jumping to.

**EDIT#1:**

for a specific row *(like 20)*, either of these will work:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A" & 20,INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & 20))
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A20",INDIRECT("Sheet2!A20" ))
```

**EDIT#2:**

Please note that if the worksheet name contains a **space** character, that name must be enclosed in **single quotes**:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'apple banana'!A20",INDIRECT("'apple banana'!A20" ))
```

Comment: How would i be able to adjust to specific cells?

Comment: @EliCollins  You would edit the formula to replace the *ROWS($1:1)* with a specific row number.  You would also replace the *"A"* with another column letter.

Comment: What would the formula look like. I've tried replacing the the first and second ROWS($1:1) as you mentioned with (20) and I'm getting error messages?

Comment: @EliCollins  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I notice I get an #REF error when I changed the name Sheets3 to something like "Apples[space]Bananas", but when remove the "space" I change it to ApplesBananas the error disappears?

Comment: @EliCollins  See my **EDIT#2**